# node js throws error on pc but not on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js

I am trying to start my `node js` server on my windows machine. On my ubuntu everything works fine and it starts up however on windows i get the following error:

```
    c:\xampp\htdocs\learningbankapi\src\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:79
        throw e
              ^
Error: no errorc:\xampp\htdocs\learningbankapi\src\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.node
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at bindings (c:\xampp\htdocs\learningbankapi\src\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:74:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\xampp\htdocs\learningbankapi\src\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\xampp\htdocs\learningbankapi\src\auth.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

The `auth.js` looks like this:

```
   var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
// Route: /login
module.exports = function (express, sequelize, router) {
    var DataTypes = require("sequelize");
    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
            id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            username: DataTypes.STRING,
            password: DataTypes.STRING,
            organization_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            user_type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            division_id: DataTypes.INTEGER


            }, {
            freezeTableName: true,
            instanceMethods: {
                retrieveByNamePassword: function (username, onSuccess, onError) {
                    User.find({include: [{ all: true }],where: {username: username}}, {})
                        .then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
                }
            }
        }
        ),
         Division = sequelize.define('division', {
            id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            organization_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            location_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            name: DataTypes.STRING
        }, {freezeTableName: true}),
        Profile = sequelize.define('profile', {
            user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            firstname: DataTypes.STRING,
            lastname: DataTypes.STRING,
            address: DataTypes.STRING,
            phone: DataTypes.STRING,
            cpr: DataTypes.STRING,
            description: DataTypes.STRING
        }, {freezeTableName: true}),
        Title = sequelize.define('title', {
            id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            organization_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
        }, {freezeTableName: true});
    User.belongsTo(Division,{foreignKey: 'division_id'});
    User.hasOne(Profile, {foreignKey: 'user_id'});
    User.belongsTo(Title, {foreignKey:'title_id'});
    router.route('/login')

        .post(function (req, res) {
            var user = User.build();

            var username = req.body.username || '';
            var password = req.body.password || '';

            if (username == '' || password == '') {
                res.status(401);
                res.json({
                    "status": 401,
                    "message": "Invalid credentials"
                });
                return;
            }
            var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
            var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);


            user.retrieveByNamePassword(username, function (users) {
                var i = 0;
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(password,users.password)) {
                    // If authentication is success, we will generate a token
                    // and dispatch it to the client
                    res.json(genToken(users));
                    return;
                } else {
                    // If authentication fails, we send a 401 back
                    res.status(401);
                    res.json({
                        "status": 401,
                        "message": "Invalid credentials"
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }, function (error) {
                res.status(401);
                res.json({
                    "status": 401,
                    "message": "Invalid credentials"
                });
                return;
            });
        });

    var genToken = function(user) {
        var expires = expiresIn(7); // 7 days
        var token = jwt.encode({
            exp: expires,
            user_id: user.id,
            organization_id: user.organization_id,
            user_type_id: user.user_type_id,
            division_id: user.division_id

        }, require('./config/secret')());

        return {
            token: token,
            expires: expires,
            user: user
        };
    };

    var expiresIn = function(numDays) {
        var dateObj = new Date();
        return dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numDays);
    };

    return router;
};
```

And my node modules are:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what might be the problem?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `bcrypt` needs VisualStudio to be installed. This is also noted in the [package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).

Comment: I have VisualStudio already installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you copy the `node_modules` directory from your Ubuntu machine? You need to exclude that directory from your copy (and I'd advise you add this directory to your `.gitignore` file) because it's very likely the module you're trying to use was compiled for the Linux system.

If you exclude the directory and run `npm install` inside that directory on the Windows server, all of your modules including `bcrypt` will be re-generated to work with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the `node_modules` you are using rely on native code that cannot be ported between different platforms.

Usually it is not a good practice to share the `node_modules` folder. Instead share only the package dependency declarations and each developer will have to call the `npm install` to be able to work on the project.

This ensures that everyone will have the packages installed that work on their platform.

As you can see [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#dependencies) depends on [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) , a tool used for compiling native addons. So that is in your case one of the sources of your problem